# How can I share the memory when i call fork() ?

Tags: c, process, fork

Last time, I questioned .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
int arr[10]={0,};
pid_t pid;
int state;
pid = fork();

if(pid == -1) // error
{
printf("can't fork, error\n");
exit(-1);
}

else if (pid == 0) // Child ( producer )
{
printf("\nProducer is created.\n");

printf("array: ");
for(c=0; c<10; c++)
{
    printf("%d ", arr[c]);
    arr[c]=c+1;
}

}

else // Mother ( consumer )
{
pid=wait(&state);
sleep(1);
printf("\nConsumer takes control of array");


printf("\narray:");

for(j=0;j<10;j++) 
{
    printf(" %d", arr[j]);
}


printf("\nConsumer is done.");

printf("\narray: ");
for ( i =0; i<10; i++)
{

    arr[i]=-1;
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);


}
printf("\ndone\n");
exit(0);
}
return 0;}
```

I want output

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

but

my out put is

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

what's the problem with my code?

=

I wrote this question,
many people said that I should use shared memory,
but I have never listen to that in class..

but I should solve in 2days.

What's the simple way to get the solution.

I found the 'shm*' but, there's no more easy way to solve this problem than shm*?

If it exists, Plz teach me the simple example .....

Thank you...

Comment: If it is just about getting it done, why don't you just write to a file and read from it. Or better yet, use pipes.

Comment: You do know that you can learn stuff via the web without having to hear it in class. This is a useful skill to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate PIPEs. It is another IPC mechanism.

From  linux manual:
int pipe(int fd[2]) -- creates a pipe and returns two file descriptors, fd[0], fd[1]. fd[0] is opened for reading, fd[1] for writing.

**Code for your requirement:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    int     fd[2], nbytes;
    pid_t   pid;
    int arr[10]={0,};
    int readbuffer[10];
    int state, c, i, j;

    pipe(fd);

    if((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        printf("can't fork, error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
            /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
            close(fd[0]);

            /* Send "arr" through the output side of pipe */
            printf("\nProducer is created.\n");

            printf("array: ");
            for(c=0; c<10; c++)
            {
                printf("%d ", arr[c]);
                arr[c]=c+1;
            }

            write(fd[1], arr, (sizeof(int)*10));
            exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
            /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
            close(fd[1]);

            pid=wait(&state);
            sleep(1);
            printf("\nConsumer takes control of array");

            /* Read in arr from the pipe */
            nbytes = read(fd[0], arr, (sizeof(int)*10));

            printf("\narray:");

            for(j=0;j<10;j++) 
            {
                printf(" %d", arr[j]);
            }

            printf("\nConsumer is done.");

            printf("\narray: ");
            for ( i =0; i<10; i++)
            {
                arr[i]=-1;
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);
            }
            printf("\ndone\n");
            exit(0);

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When forking, private memory pages are marked as "copy-on-write", so that each program can continue without interference of the other (otherwise you'd run into a stack corruption in no time).

If you want memory to be shared, you will have to specify that explicitly. One such way is via the `mmap` syscall (header: `<sys/mman.h>`):

```
mmap(NULL, 10 * sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

On success, this returns a pointer to a memory region large enough to hold 10 `int`s, has read and write permissions, is not associated with any file (`MAP_ANONYMOUS`) and will be shared with forks (`MAP_SHARED`). You should release the memory with `munmap` when you're done.

This means you'll simply have to change your array to a pointer and allocate the memory at runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *arr;
    pid_t pid;
    int state;
    int c, i, j;

    arr = mmap(NULL, 10 * sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if(arr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("mmap failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) // error
    {
        printf("can't fork, error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    else if(pid == 0) // Child ( producer )
    {
        printf("\nProducer is created.\n");

        printf("array: ");
        for(c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[c]);
            arr[c] = c + 1;
        }
    }

    else // Mother ( consumer )
    {
        pid = wait(&state);
        sleep(1);
        printf("\nConsumer takes control of array");

        printf("\narray:");
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", arr[j]);
        }
        printf("\nConsumer is done.");

        printf("\narray: ");
        for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = -1;
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\ndone\n");
    }

    munmap(arr, 10 * sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MatteoItalia `wait` is used for the actual synchronization... I just left the `sleep` because the OP put it there.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice. My bad.